# Make a DIV overlap elements below it

Tags: css, overlap

I have a div which I toggle using Prototypes toggle function. That works nice. The problem I have is that the elements below the div are moving around on the page as I toggle the div. I want them to stay and I want the div to overlap them.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Make this a jsFiddle so we can see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `position:absolute;` on the DIV that is being toggled and `position:relative` on the container of all the DIVs.